# Inject activity's ViewModel into fragment's ViewModel

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, dagger

I've setup a project very similar to [`GithubBrowserSample`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample). So, the dagger setup is the same.

Consider there are `ActivityViewModel` and `FragmentViewModel`, which have non-zero arg constructor, so they are being acquired from `ViewModelProviders` via custom `ViewModelProvider.Factory`.

What I want is to instruct dagger to inject already created instance of `ActivityViewModel` in following code:

```
    class FragmentViewModel @Inject constructor(
        private val activityViewModel: ActivityViewModel
        private val foo: Foo
    ) : ViewModel() {
        ...
    }
```

With current declaration Dagger will create a **new** instance of `ActivityViewModel` regardless that there already exists one.

This happens, because there exists an `@Inject` annotated constructor for `ActivityViewModel`.

So, dagger is free to assume, that it is the correct way of providing an instance of `ActivityViewModel` to `FragmentViewModel`.

I know how to make things for ordinary Dagger, but I do not know how to do this for Dagger-Android, and this questions is specifically for Dagger-Android setup.

As a dirty solution I'm currently manually setting that instance:

```
    class MyFragment : Fragment {
      ...
      override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(FragmentViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.activityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!, viewModelFactory).get(ActivityViewModel::class.java)
      }
      ...
    }
```

What's the correct way of injecting parent's `ViewModel` into child's `ViewModel`?

Comment: Why would you want one viewmodel in another in the first place?

Comment: @DeividasStrioga, what's the problem with that? Assume I want to delegate some kind of job to parent `ViewModel`, because that's not the job of child `ViewModel`, i.e. establishing communication between fragments.

Comment: According to their purpose, they should help populating the view and reacting to ui events. Fragments/activities should be issuing commands and communicating in between. It looks to me that it is better architectural decision.

Comment: should the communication not be done through a common model, or model to model that each viewmodel knows about rather than viewmodels knowing about another viewmodel? I'm trying to understand how any delegation should be necessary, surely information should be presented to the correct viewmodel from the model dirently, not through another viewmodel.

Comment: @DeividasStrioga, assume you have a `ProgressBar` inside your activity, which is currently hidden. Now, inside your fragment you are issuing an action, that should initiate the `ProgressBar` to be displayed. How are you going to establish this communication?

Comment: @azizbekian First of all I would use databinding, if progressbar is shown on some fragment button click, it is ease to set a listener to affect an activity method. If not using databinding I would do it from fragment directly informing it's activity.

Comment: @DeividasStrioga, sir, how does it matter whether you are using DataBinding or ordinary `findViewById()`? `I would do it from fragment directly informing it's activity` Why fragment should know anything about activity's view hierarchy?

Comment: @azizbekian It is just easier with databinding. Well fragment knowing about it's parent activity is more appropriate than fragment's viewmodel knowing about another view's (activitiy's) viewmodel. Viewmodel should not know anything about it's own view, let alone other view's helper. Do you have multiple fragment s in ono activity at the same time?

Comment: MAybe you could set a listener from activity to fragment's viewmodel after it's creation.

Comment: `It is just easier with databinding` Thanks, I already use databinding, I just meant that it isn't related with the actual question. In my case `ViewModel` doesn't know anything about its own view, neither another view's helper. My `FragmentViewModel` delegates the job to `ActivityViewModel`, which in turn dispatches the event to activity via `LiveData`.

Comment: `MAybe you could set a listener from activity to fragment's viewmodel after it's creation` It's exactly the solution that I've marked in the question as "dirty". Thanks for thoughts.

Comment: @azizbekian by another view's helper I mean it's viewmodel.  `It's exactly the solution that I've marked in the question as "dirty".` No, I am suggesting that your activity implements some sort of interface, let's say ProgressBarListener. In fragment, onCreate set this listener from activity to this viewmodel (if this event does not come from UI action). At least that's what I would do. Hope that helps.

Comment: @azizbekian what you are trying to achieve can be done with the right module scope. Can you share your snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not** an answer to the question, rather this is an approach that I've come up with and currently use.

Having declared following extension functions:

```
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> Fragment.getViewModel(
    factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory()
) = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(T::class.java)

inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> Fragment.getParentViewModel(
    factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory()
) = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!, factory).get(T::class.java)
```

Then in a fragment class we can declare following:

```
private val parentViewModel by lazy { getParentViewModel<ParentViewModel>(viewModelFactory) }
private val childViewModel by lazy {
  val field = getViewModel<ChildViewModel>(viewModelFactory)
  field.parentViewModel = parentViewModel
  field
}
```